# Подключение dll библиотеки в Qt Creator

Tags: .net, qt, dll, nfc

Собственно нашёл интересную библиотеку dotNET, как раз идеально подходит под мой проект, но документации мало и ума не приложу как её в Qt добавить, т.к. там нет ни заголовочных файлов, ни .o файла. https://www.winsoft.sk/nnfclib.htm 
К тому же она платная, покупать кота в мешке я как-то не хочу. Каким образом это дело линковать вообще? Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению, в проекте на Qt применить этот код не возможно. dll файлы .Net это сборки(Assembly), а не динамически подключаемые библиотеки. Так как сборка содержит IL для виртуальной машины CLR, а не нативный код, её невозможно подключить к программе не на языках группы .Net

Кроме того, язык C# запускается на CLR, а не компилируется в команды машины.  Библиотека Qt же работает с языком программирования C++, проекты с её использованием собираются именно в них.